# How fix "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Org1MSP]" error in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, organization, peer

Currently I am using Hyperledger Fabric 1.4, and I am trying to modify the basic-network. I am trying to add an org2 with one peer. Whenever I try to invoke the chaincode from the peer on the second organization (Org2) I get the following error:

Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = access denied: channel [] creator org [Org2MSP]

My current network components are: 
org1, with two peers 
org2, with one peer 
CA1 
CA2 
Ordere 
CLI 
and a channel called "mychannel"

I am able to create the channel "mychannel" and join the 3 peers from the two organizations. Also, I am able to install the chaincode on three of the peers from both organizations. And I am instantiating the chaincode on peer0 in Org1

Part of the Ordere logs:

```
2019-05-13 13:17:42.384 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 003 Getting block information from block storage
2019-05-13 13:17:42.970 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] Initialize -> INFO 004 Starting system channel 'testchainid' with genesis block hash f1bcfe55588bd24faaa699bc740045455283b63950436a36d5cf473f4b3d8f81 and orderer type solo
2019-05-13 13:17:42.970 UTC [orderer.common.server] Start -> INFO 005 Starting orderer:
 Version: 1.4.1
 Commit SHA: 87074a7
 Go version: go1.11.5
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2019-05-13 13:17:42.970 UTC [orderer.common.server] Start -> INFO 006 Beginning to serve requests
2019-05-13 13:21:30.921 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 007 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.20.0.6:36544 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=27.428231ms
2019-05-13 13:21:30.927 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 008 Getting block information from block storage
2019-05-13 13:21:31.038 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] newChain -> INFO 009 Created and starting new chain mychannel
2019-05-13 13:21:31.044 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00a streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.20.0.6:36542 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=152.538972ms
2019-05-13 13:22:11.867 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 00b Error reading from 172.20.0.6:36578: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-05-13 13:22:11.867 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00c streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.20.0.6:36578 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=5.757971ms
2019-05-13 13:22:22.295 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 00d Error reading from 172.20.0.8:34272: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-05-13 13:22:22.295 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00e streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.20.0.8:34272 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=7.238573847s
2019-05-13 13:23:46.748 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 00f Error reading from 172.20.0.8:34362: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-05-13 13:23:46.748 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 010 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.20.0.8:34362 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=49.20235ms
```

In summery, I can not invoke the chaincode from the second organization (Org2) because of channel access error. 
Note:
I am generating the CA and I have checked the files and it seems to be correct

If anyone can help I would appreciate it. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by wrong MSPID name for example "orgMSP" is wrong as it starts with lowercase "o"
to solve the problem use correct MSPID

```
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to answer if you have shared the peer logs.

The error could be because of the Certificates to sign the transaction.Double check your certificate received from CA and also checked the certificates and path used inside the docker container of peer1.